# I want to use PDF/TIFF Document Text Detection service from google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Google cloud vision api is very powerful and now they have support for pdf format, but the documentation is getting me confused, can someone pls guide a noob how to set up and process a pdf file using vision api.

kind of like starter tutorial

ref: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#vision-web-detection-gcs-protocol

The confusion is how to pass the command arguments, and send my sample file and retrieve the results in csv or json format

Should i use my windows command line or cloudshell on google cloud

There is good starter reference for other services , if you look at this https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#vision-detect-labels-gcloud, they have clearly given commands to use in different envs

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following curl command as a base and run it within your Google Cloud Shell session:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) --header "Content-Type: application/json"   --request POST   --data '{ "requests":[  {"inputConfig": { "gcsSource": {  "uri": "gs://<Your Bucket>/<Your PDF FIle>"},"mimeType":"application/pdf"},"features": [{"type":"DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"}],"outputConfig": {"gcsDestination":{"uri": "gs://<Your destination bucket/"},"batchSize": 2}}]}' https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/files:asyncBatchAnnotate
```

Then, you'll get an operation object as a response like this: `"name": "operations/<This is your operation ID>"`.

After that, you'll get your results with the GET request, for instance:

```
curl --request GET https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/operations/<The Operation ID>?key=<Your API Key>
```

Comment: Thanks but i am getting this error

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ya29.GqQBKwbpRoXBYrkSjEXAc19CwRxf-eM3Fq1plGlO6EC_ggL7vMNdr12IYqy_NmQ9dIem6PCrNkTQnH0913E7l1QqvBE1WnB6uNDBqjV-d4t3MEzI4ZJYvLvaDVljIji_U-z0vJpcleNh697AN6uwzlXeRsvwT_6iLMciybNfurRIDPPmCYfWswjLMKCfiJQMZ1ZJrVK0LEEqOSMLsCpWolAIPYiQGHQ
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Comment: Could you please specify on which request are you getting this response? If it's possible, please paste your curl request, but avoid sharing your API Key for security reasons